# Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation

Tags: windows, mount, ntfs, hibernate

Whenever I boot Ubuntu, I get a message that it cannot mount my windows partition, and I can choose to either wait, skip or manually mount.

When I try to enter my Windows partition through Nautilus I get a message saying that this partition is hibernated and that I need to enter the file system and properly close it, something I have done with no problem so I don't know why this happens.

Here's my partition table, if any more data is needed please let me know.

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    20000767     9999360   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        20002814   478001151   228999169    5  Extended
/dev/sda3   *   478001152   622532607    72265728    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       622532608   625141759     1304576   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda5        20002816   478001151   228999168   83  Linux
```

Comment: Do you hibernate it or do you shutdown Windows before you see the error message? I have this problem too, but I am sure I shutdown Windows 8 Release Preview instead of hibernating it. What version of Windows do you use?

Answer (score 430, accepted):

A [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1008117) has been filed about the Nautilus dialog you are seeing as it recommends a potentially dangerous option that could result in data loss.  Please do not run the command in this dialog unless you want to **delete** your saved Windows session and potentially lose unsaved work.

> ### Explanation: Why Linux can't open hibernated Windows partitions:
>
> You are seeing this error because you hibernated Windows instead of
>   turning it off the normal way (in newer versions of Windows, hibernate
>   might be the default option).
>
> - Hibernating saves the current state information to the hard disk and then powers down the computer.
> - Shutting down the computer closes all programs and ends all running processes before powering down the computer.
>
> When you turn off Windows by hibernating it, you are essentially
>   pausing the system and saving all of that information (into a big file
>   called `hiberfil.sys`)  This way when you resume from hibernation all
>   of your applications and files will be exactly how you left them.  It
>   also sets a flag in `hiberfil.sys` to let other Operating Systems know
>   that Windows is hibernated.
>
> Making changes to your Windows (`ntfs`) partition while it is
>   hibernated could be dangerous--it could cause Windows to not resume
>   from hibernation or to crash after resuming.  Because of this, the
>   tool (`ntfs-3g`) that mounts (opens) the partition will not mount it
>   in read-write mode if it sees a hibernation flag.  As such, Nautilus,
>   the default file browser, will not be able to automatically open this
>   partition--hence the error message that you see--because it is trying
>   to open it in read-write mode.

### Workaround for all versions of Windows:

There are three ways to mount a hibernated Windows partition:

1. Boot into Windows and power down the system by shutting it down
   completely.  You may then boot back into Ubuntu and the partition will mount in read-write mode automatically when you open it in Nautilus.  *Note that the "Shut Down" option may not be the one
   displayed in your start menu by default.  You may need to click the
   button next to it to see further options.*
2. Manually mount the filesystem in read only mode.

   - Check to see if you have a mount point (folder for mounting your partition in) for your Windows partition in the folder `/media`
     using this command:

     `ls /media`
   - If you don't see a folder for your Windows partition, you should create one with the following command:

     `sudo mkdir /media/windows`
   - Next, mount the partition in read-only mode onto this folder with this command:

     `mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda3 /media/windows`

     Note that you should change `/media/windows` if your mountpoint is called something else.
   - Now you will be able to view/open files on your Windows partition using any program in Ubuntu.  However you will not be able to write 
     to the partition or modify any files as it is in read only mode.
3. If you need to mount the partition in read-write mode and are not
   able to or willing to boot into Windows and shut it down completely
   there is a third option.  However, it is not included here because it **completely deletes** `hiberfil.sys` and will cause you to lose all
   unsaved information in the hibernated Windows programs.  The following is a quotation
   from `man ntfs-3g` about the option that would be used to do this.

   ```
   remove_hiberfile
                 Unlike in case of  read-only  mount,  the  read-write  mount  is
                 denied  if  the  NTFS  volume is hibernated. One needs either to
                 resume Windows and shutdown it  properly,  or  use  this  option
                 which  will  remove  the  Windows hibernation file. Please note,
                 this means that the saved Windows  session  will  be  completely
                 lost. Use this option under your own responsibility.
   ```

### Solution (only for Windows 8 and 10):

There is a new feature in Windows 8 called [Fast Startup](http://www.typicaltips.com/2013/02/disable-fast-startup-in-windows-8.html). If this feature is enabled (which it is by default), Windows 8 does not actually completely shutdown when you choose shutdown. Instead, it does a "hybrid shutdown". This is something like hibernating; it makes booting Windows 8 back up faster. So, you need to disable this feature to be able to shut it down properly, and be able to mount the Windows partitions. To do this, boot into your Windows 8 and:

> **Note**: disabling Fast Startup will most likely make your Windows 8 take a longer time to boot. There are no "exact" numbers, but let's say that if it took you 10 seconds to boot into Windows 8, it will now take you 50 seconds after disabling this feature.

1. Open **Control Panel** in the small icons view and click on **Power Options**. (see [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duyd8.jpg))
2. Click on **Choose what the power buttons do**. (see [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkc2M.jpg))
3. Click on **Change settings that are currently unavailable**.
   (see [screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGvh7.jpg))
4. Uncheck **Turn on fast startup (recommended)**. (see [screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjvol.jpg))

Click on **Save changes**. Now, shutdown Windows 8 and boot back into Ubuntu.

If you still aren't able to mount without getting errors, you may need to turn off hibernation completely. Open an elevated Command Prompt (right click on the shortcut, click on “Run as Administrator”), and input:

```
powercfg /h off
```

**Source: [Fast Startup - Turn On or Off in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html)**.

Comment: None of these works for me. The only I am able to mount Win 8 partition on ubuntu is to press "restart" in windows, then boot ubuntu.

Comment: Hello, I change the seatings for windows 8.1 as you mention. But unfortunately i still have the error massage I had previously. please help me,

Comment: There is this link http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/#fastrestart that could be useful  --- it suggests issuing the command `powercfg /h off` on Windows.

Comment: I have the "fast boot" option disabled and I always boot to Fedora by rebooting windows yet it still says that "it's in an unsafe state" is there anything else to do?

Comment: I am having the same exact problem as @arielnmz . I disabled "fast boot" according to the "Solution (only for Windows 8)", yet I still cannot mount it R/W in Ubuntu 14. I can mount it RO but not RW. Any idea why this works for others but not for me?

Comment: @arielnmz I solved the problem by performing one more step (in addition to the above): [powercfg /h off](http://askubuntu.com/a/457401/363039)

Comment: @ShahariaAzam I'll offer a bounty if you want to write up your solution here as a separate answer.

Comment: @adempewolff I will. Check back soon! Here is the solution as a separate answer. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation/706054#706054

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I would have mess things up had I not seen your post.

Comment: Thanks,it work for my. I'm enter again and went to "restart".

Comment: What if the message appears after using reset button? Is it really needed to load windows first, or the flag can safely be dropped?

Comment: It works on second method. thanks for perfect answer.

Comment: aaaaaah! I might have known! My wife has been using this laptop! of course did not shut down anything properly, let it run out of batter power. Thanks for saving my evening

Comment: A detailed GUI instruction on how to turn off the fast booting option on Windows 10 can be found [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1152001/shutdown-windows-10-truly-for-a-dual-booting-system). It works for me!

Comment: thanks friend, very useful: powercfg /h off , I have been able to acces to my files on the ntfs  windows 10 partition again.

Comment: @adempewolff I like your answer. In my case `sudo mount  -t  -ntfs-3g  -o  r o /dev/sda2  /media/ubuntu/5C04866104863DD0/` results `mount: unknown filesystem type  -ntfs-3g`. I am trying in live CD.

Comment: @adempewolff  I do this for get a file that is located in window's desktop. I need nothing else of window's partition and my windows is damaged and it is not loaded.

Comment: I have followed all of these steps before, and just recently good old Windoze *reverted* these settings back to turning on fast startup. Unbelievable and frustrating.

Comment: I noticed that this applies not just to the system partition, but to all NTFS volumes I've had mounted in Windows. Can I mount those in RW mode, or is this whole thing a crucial precaution for every volume Windows had mounted?

Comment: Other than losing all your hibernated data, is there anything particularly risky about deleting the hibernation file?

Comment: If you are not afraid of losing the hibernated data, your command is: `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sdxy /mnt`

Comment: I tried the `remove-hiberfile` option but got `Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.`

Comment: I really don't remember hibernating my Windows but it indeed was the solution

Comment: The **"Solution (only for Windows 8 and 10)"** also worked for me on Windows 11

Comment: remove_hiberfile option did it for me

Answer (score 170):

EDIT: **DOING THIS *MIGHT* HAVE DANGEROUS CONSEQUENCES** and Windows might fail to boot or corrupt the filesystem upon booting.

---

Use [ntfsfix](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsfix) in the terminal, even if you can't access Windows

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY
```

where XY is the partition, e.g. `a2` (`/dev/sda2`) or `b1` (`/dev/sdb1`)

ntfsfix repairs some fundamental NTFS inconsistencies, resets the NTFS journal file and schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows.

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: A little bit of explanation would be really nice :-) Certainly there is man page, but since you wrote it here, it would be good to further improve it but explaining what this command does.

Comment: I tried that but it stills returns "Windows is hibernated, refused to mount. Remount failed: Operation not permitted"

Comment: Nice! this should be the chosen answer...

Comment: You do *NOT* want to do this.  Doing so will result in the filesystem being corrupted when you resume your hibernated windows session.

Comment: I concur with @psusi: **this is very dangerous and could result in all data lost** like [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/659728/unable-to-load-windows8-x-partition-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Note that you [should](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G#Damaged_NTFS_filesystems) `umount /dev/XY` before running `ntfsfix`.

Comment: It worked for me. But GParted was not able to mount after the fix. I added back the NTFS partition in /etc/fstab (I removed it because I was not able to boot with it). I rebooted and the partition mounted without problem.

Comment: @psusi: Should this answer be edited, deleted, or just downvoted?

Comment: I did this and got an error "Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Remount failed: Operation not permitted"

Comment: Sometimes it is the only option when windows refuses to launch. Unless you have a windows recovery CD and you can launch chkdsk from there.

Comment: For what it is worth, this is the solution that worked when a non-boot NTFS drive refused to mount.  The system also had hibernate off, and the ntfs-3g functions like force, recover, and remove_hiberfile had no effect.  My guess is attached drives must not get a good treament even when windows is ended with "shutdown /p"

Answer (score 58):

If you want to terminate the hibernated session, run this command in a Terminal(press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open Terminal)

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY
```

where `XY` is the partition. ex: *sda2* or *sdb1*

This also works if you couldn't get into Win8.

Comment: I am not sure fixing an NTFS partition from Ubuntu is a good idea for a hibernating fast startup Windows 8.1. Instead, I solved the problem from within Windows 8.1: [powercfg /h off](http://askubuntu.com/a/457401/363039)

Comment: I did this and got an error "Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Remount failed: Operation not permitted"

Comment: @BillTheApe but works, in my situation, I am not able to access my windows anymore.

Answer (score 21):

It's because of Windows 8's fast startup feature.

Temporary solution would be to go back in Windows and restart the system (instead of shutdown). Permanent solution is to disable fast startup.

You can use this guide to disable fast startup in Windows 8: http://itsfoss.com/solve-ntfs-mount-problem-ubuntu-windows-8-dual-boot/

Comment: This was exactly what the problem was for me and doing a restart from windows to boot into linux rather than a shutdown is a great way to verify that this is the correct solution for you. The ntfsfix solution below did not work for me, whereas this one did.

Comment: same issue on Windows 10

Comment: restarting windows instead of shuting-down solved problem also for me. ntfs-3g flag remove_hiberfile did not help.

Comment: Did you actually look to see if the hibernation was removed?

Comment: Thanks, restarting was good advice! I was trying to mount the disk in order to reset a forgotten password, so of course I can't change any Windows fast boot settings.

Answer (score 19):

My solution was to call a `mntwindows` script in `/etc/rc.local`. This script would check for hibernation and if hibernated mount as read only. In order to make sure the script may always be called I placed it in `/bin` and marked it as executable. The contents of the script are as follows

```sh
sudo mount /dev/sda[Partition Number] /media/[Any existing folder name]

#Mounts Windows
if [ $? -eq 14 ]
then
  echo "Windows is sleeping, I'm mounting as read-only"
  sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda[Partition Number] /media/[Any existing folder name]
fi
```

Comment: Great solution. Many thanks. It worked for me on an ancient eMachines E442 which got accidentally trashed on shutdown. +1

Comment: I believe there is no need to create a separate mounting script in `/etc/rc.local`. A single line in `/etc/fstab` did the trick for me: `/dev/sdaX /media/[mount-folder] ntfs-3g nofail,nodev,errors=remount-ro 0 0`. I initially assumed `errors=remount-ro` is what is automatically mounting the drive as readonly if Windows is hibernated. But it also works **without** that option as tested on Linux Kernel 5.3+

Answer (score 15):

Windows 8 adds a "fast startup" feature. It does make Windows start up faster after a shutdown, but as a side effect it ends up putting your filesystem in that hibernating state.

To disable this feature in Win 8, search for "choose what the power buttons do" under settings, click the shield to unlock the checkboxes, and you can enable or disable the fast startup from there.

The caveat mentioned earlier, that you want to really shutdown Windows and not restart to get easy access from Linux, still applies.

Comment: I disabled "fast startup" in my Windows 8.1. It didn't help. I can only mount RO. This is weird.

Answer (score 11):

Just for completion, here is another command to mount a partition as read-only (useful for hibernated Windows partitions):

```
udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sda3 --options ro
```

If you have permission to mount the partition using the file manager (if you are an administrator, for example), then you should be able to run this command without using `sudo`.

This is available in the newest Ubuntu versions (like 13.04 and 13.10).

If `udisksctl` isn't available, then maybe `udisks` is. It has different arguments, so check the manpage.

Comment: I Love this! :D

Comment: This is a great solution if you don't want to start windows again.

Comment: Yes it works for me! My windows wasn't booting so this was the only way out :)

Answer (score 11):

For windows 10, I figured out how to turn off the fast startup. Did one screencast to solve that. Go to **Control Panel** > **Hardware and Sound** > **Power Options** > **System Settings** Then click on 'Change Settings that are currently unavailable' and remove tick from 'Turn on fast startup'. Source : http://blog.shahariaazam.com/fast-startup-turn-on-or-off-in-windows-10

Answer (score 11):

**It has become even more simple (Windows 8<sup>+</sup>)**

Just **force shutdown** or you can say **complete shutdown** your windows system before rebooting to Ubuntu OS.

Well how will I do that?

Very simple: <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> + **Shutdown**

i,e Hold <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> key while you click the **Shutdown** button in Windows to shutdown it completely.

<sub>Of course it will make your windows boot little slower next time. :)</sub>

Answer (score 10):

on Windows 8 it's normal.
You need to shut down Windows 8 via cmd by entering `shutdown /f /s /t 0` then it might work.

Comment: I believe `shutdown /s /t 0` is sufficient... no need to use force

Comment: @Matt I tried `shutdown /s /t 0`. This doesn't work. This is despite me disabling fast boot prior to that. I can only mount that NTFS partition RO.

Comment: @root `shutdown /f /s /t 0` doesn't work either. Something must have changed in either Ubuntu 14.04 or Windows 8.1 since this answer was posted.

Comment: @BillTheApe I continue to use this technique on Arch Linux which is a rolling release. I humbly suggest that your problem lies elsewhere

Comment: @Matt You were right. The problem indeed lied elsewhere: disabling fast startup + `shutdown /f /s /t 0` was sufficient for Windows 7. It is no longer sufficient for Windows 8.1. **In addition** to what's required for Windows 7, Windows 8.1 requires one more step: [powercfg /h off](http://askubuntu.com/a/457401/363039)

Answer (score 10):

## For Windows 8+

You need to disable the "Fast Startup" feature. To quote the How-To-Geek:

> Open up your power options by hitting Windows+X or right-clicking your
> Start menu and selecting Power Options. In the Power Options window,
> click “Choose what the power buttons do.”
>
> [image]
>
> If this is the first time you’ve messed with these settings, you’ll
> need click “Change settings that are currently unavailable” to make
> the Fast Startup option available for configuration.
>
> [image]
>
> Scroll to the bottom of the window and you should see “Turn on fast
> startup (recommended)"
>
> [image]

**Uncheck** the "fast startup" box.

Then, shut down Windows 10, and you should be able to mount the NTFS partition from Ubuntu just fine.

---

<sup>How-To-Geek quotation taken from [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/).</sup>

Comment: This is pretty much what the section for Windows 8 and 10 in the accepted answer says.

Comment: @muru - *shrugs* this has screenshots

Comment: *shrugs* meh, so does that answer - the numbers in the list are links to screenshots

Comment: In my dual-boot setting with Windows 11, the trick that did it for me was not only to disable the "fast startup", but also to uncheck the "Hibernate" box. It was necessary even though I did not actually hibernate windows.

Answer (score 9):

In my experience adempewolff's popular and helpful answer above was necessary, but not sufficient, to allow me to mount my Windows NTFS partition for writing with Ubuntu. As instructed elsewhere I turned Fast Startup off before trying to install Ubuntu and I removed the Hibernate Option on the "Shutdown" menu, too.

I still couldn't write to my Windows partition from Ubuntu.

I found I also had to boot Windows 8.1, start a Windows authorized command line (right click on the Windows button on the bottom left to get to this option easily), allow it through the Windows authorization box, and then enter the command:

```
powercfg /h off
```

You can check the results with:

```
powercfg /a
```

After making this change I was able to freely access the Windows 8.1 partition from Ubuntu, whether I quit Windows by shutting down or by restarting.

---

I found that I was able to later reverse this and still access the partition (but keeping Fast Startup unchecked at all times, as above, and never asking for Windows hibernation of course). The command to reverse it is, predictably:

```
powercfg /h on
```

I assume something was left over from Windows installation that needed to be cleared by booting with hibernation turned off in this particular way.

There should be no reason to undo the first step like this as far as I know--it may provide a bit of extra safety to leave `powercfg /h off`.

See the [Ubuntu man page for the Windows NTFS handler](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ntfs-3g.8.html) for a bit more information.

Comment: I suspect that  you would not have needed to mess with `powercfg` if you had not disabled manual hibernation, though I could be wrong ...

Answer (score 8):

- Boot into Windows and then restart it. Don't shut down.
- In the grub menu select "Ubuntu" and press <kbd>Return</kbd>. After the Ubuntu has booted up, open the NTFS partition. It should now open.

Comment: Note that this works even if you can't log in to Windows (e.g., due to a lost password). You can restart from the Windows Start Screen.

Comment: And how do you mount this if this is a HDD from a dead windows device you just want to clean up then archive?

Answer (score 5):

You can mount it in read only mode
For it, first you have to create a directory as mount point:

```
sudo mkdir /media/*youruser*/newdisk
```

Later, mount the drive with:

```
sudo mount -t "ntfs" -ro "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda4" "/media/*youruser*/newdisk"
```

Change words with `*`, with your *user name*. `/dev/sda4` could be also different, depending on the partition is the one where windows 8 is installed.

Note the args values are taken for your particular error message, for other users take the error message, change `-o` by `-ro` and type appropriate user name.

Also, note, with this method, you cannot edit, write or create new files in the windows drive.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answer you can go into Windows 7 or Windows 8 (W8: this is the default power-off action, it isn't a true shutdown in a sense), open a command line with super user privileges and type `powercfg -h off`.

The caveat is now you Windows computer will not be able to Hibernate at all.  However, you will be able to mount your Windows partitions without doing surgery on it.

Answer (score 2):

It is more than likely that this is happening because you are booting from a Windows 8 system. What they have done is make it so that when you turn off your computer it really goes into hibernation for a quicker boot when you switch it on again.

What you will need to do is to go into the Control Panel section of Windows 8, navigate to power options and disable the quick start up option so that when you shut down, you will actually have shut down your system and as a result the files on the partition will be able to be accessed and edited.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I could solve it by following the recipe from the Arch Wiki:

- Boot into Windows
- As an administrator, run `powercfg /h off`
- Shutdown Windows

I also changed `/etc/fstab` to a UUID to refer to the NTFS partition, after a first attempt failed, where I did not use the `powercfg` command but disabled it by clicking through the GUI. Not sure, why using a UUID should make any difference (in the Wiki, it is not explained further). But at least it is working again.

---

Source: Arch Wiki ([NTFS-3G: Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G#Metadata_kept_in_Windows_cache.2C_refused_to_mount)):

> The problem is due to a feature introduced in Windows 8 called "fast startup". When fast startup is enabled, part of the metadata of all mounted partitions are restored to the state they were at the previous closing down. As a consequence, changes made on Linux may be lost. This can happen to any NTFS partition when selecting "Shut down" or "Hibernate" under Windows 8 or 10. Leaving Windows by selecting "Restart", however, is apparently safe.
>
> To enable writing to the partitions on other operating systems, be sure fast restart is disabled. This can be achieved by issuing as an administrator the command:
>
> ```
>    powercfg /h off
> ```
>
> You can check the current settings on `Control Panel` > `Hardware and Sound` > `Power Options` > `System Setting` > `Choose what the power buttons do`. The box `Turn on fast startup` should either be disabled or missing.
>
> If you cannot mount your NTFS partition even when following this guide, try using the UUID instead of device name in /etc/fstab for all NTFS partitions. Here's an [fstab example](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab#UUIDs).

Answer (score 1):

**@abhishek** ansvered correctly, I had not only ntfs mount problem, wifi didn't work after rebooting from Windows 8.1 to Ubuntu too. The best solution is to switch fast boot in Windows 8.1 off. Go to power management and press **Choose what the power buttons do -> Change settings that are currently unavailable**. Then look down the window, find a flag "Turn on fast startup (recommended)" and switch in off.
Click **Save changes**, so now you wont have this problem!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this (in Windows 10) by removing the hiberfil.sys by

```
powercfg /h off
```

then turn it back

```
powercfg /h on
```

*I tried with the first answer and it worked, but - the problem came back after rebooting*

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 and Windows 8 both act funny about shutting down. Delete the fast boot option in Windows and if using Windows ten, make sure you reinstall the home option, which looks like a house, from Windows 8.. Then use it to shut down, not restart, when you want to go into Linux, or the error will continue to pop up, and when in Linux you cannot access the one drive... Or more than one Windows drive on my system... As I have one drive I use for sharing files between Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a mess of a thread. To mount a NTFS partition `ntfs-3g -o rw /dev/sdb1 /media/Windows` or `ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sdb1 /media/Windows` for read-only, if `rw` fails. Just make sure the device and mount point correspond to what you're using on you're system. It's not likely everyone who reads this will have their Windows NTFS partition on /dev/sdb1.

Turning off fast start in Windows 8 and up is a necessity for lasting effect. But a good one-off is to hold the power button until the machine shuts down. It won't hibernate then. You can also disable 'fast boot' in the bios/uefi, which sometimes helps.

After quite a few of the listed solutions, Windows must be shut down, rebooted, and shut down again for them to work. Other times, with Linux solutions, Linux must be shut down and rebooted for the method to work.

For instance `sudo ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sdb1 /path to mount point` will remove the hibernation file preventing access to the NTFS volume, but afterward, the system should be shut down and rebooted, and THEN try to mount `rw`, as above, or with `,rw` appended to the mount options in `/etc/fstab` for the NTFS volume.

If you want any file system to mount, regardless of what device the system gives it, which can change, you can find the UUID of the drive with `ls -al /dev/disk/by-uuid` which gives something like this:

`marky12@linuxxx:~$ ls -al /dev/disk/by-uuid total 0 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 200 Sep 28 23:32 . drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 120 Sep 28 23:32 .. lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Sep 28 23:34 171aadc8-f84e-4011-9a57-XXXXXXXXXXXX -> ../../sda1 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Sep 28 23:34 1aa1b978-565d-4430-a92a-XXXXXXXXXXXX -> ../../sda3 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Sep 28 23:34 2353a9b0-8847-4541-87d8-XXXXXXXXXXXX -> ../../sda6 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Sep 28 23:34 5aaa6253-fe3a-43cd-81b1-XXXXXXXXXXXX -> ../../sda7 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Sep 28 23:34 XXXXXXXXXXXX -> ../../sda2 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Sep 28 23:34 7ac1b3cb-0a73-4f30-bea2-XXXXXXXXXXXX -> ../../sda4 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Sep 28 23:34 ac1d849d-7aed-40c2-b1d9-XXXXXXXXXXXX -> ../../sda8 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Sep 28 23:34 fb2d05ee-21f9-4139-a216-XXXXXXXXXXXX -> ../../sda5 t`

The big long numbers are UUIDs. which the system won't change. You can use them in `/etc/fstab` like so

UUID=fb2d05ee-21f9-4139-a216-XXXXXXXXXXXX /media/drive ntfs defaults,user.auto,rw 0 0` Then, if you switch some drives around, and the device node changes from /dev/sdb1 to /dev/sdc1, the system will still know what drive you mean.

But if you make an identical image of a drive, it will have the same UUID. If you try to mount both on the same system, it won't work, even if you use device nodes, i.e. /dev/sdb1.

So, you have to use the mount option `no-uuid` for one of them, and then you can mount both.

So, my impression is that if we all take a deep breath and relax a bit before tackling mysterious computer problems, no one will rush right past the solution.

Answer (score 1):

One of the latest windows dirty tricks courtesy of microsuck. It now keeps your data hostage by not cleanly unmounting its own filesystem and keeping journaling/paging data or whatever in a swap file, WHICH IS ON THE PARTITION. Go figure that one out.

There's a check box buried deep in the "control panel" to disable this, which is probably how they cover their asses in court if ever somenoe calls them out on this abuse, which clearly falls under the computer misuse act in most jurisdictions. I think you have to look for "what the power buttons do", then change another check box to enable changing those settings from the default, and a few other hoops iirc.

W**dows is a complete malware-infested malware joke excuse for an OS, no idea how m$ are tolerated by the legal system or why people even still use their garbage products after ~= 40 years of constant failure, abuse, plagiarism, and blatant disrespect even for their own users.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with

```
$ sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
```

and

```
$ sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdXY
```

replace the sdXY with your windows partition e.g. sda3